# material UI popover - position on small screen

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying for some time to figure out a way to position material ui popover under my anchor, and leave it like that always even on smaller screens.

Here is a [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-yvcqu?file=/demo.js).

This is the best I got, but the scroll is not really on the body at this point its on the popover container `div`, and that does not help me.

Just to explain, I know I can use `AnchorElement` with position but on smaller screens, the popover will just hide the `Anchor`, I would like the popover to always be under it, and just make the body scroll, so I can see the full popover content when I scroll down.

```
import React from "react";
import {makeStyles,MuiThemeProvider,createMuiTheme} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function SimplePopover() {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const theme2 = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiButton: {
        root: {
          top: 400
        }
      },
      MuiPopover: {
        root: {
        },
        paper: {
          
          height: 500
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme2}>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
         Open Popover with anchor
      </Button>
      <Popover
        id="popover-with-anchor"
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
          vertical: 'top',
          horizontal: 'center',
        }}
      >
       Popover content.
   </Popover>
   </MuiThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Images for example. When popover is bigger than the screen it fits itself in the screen and go overs the anchor

[image]

instead of being under the anchor

[image]

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do and what exactly is the issue. Please create a working example (you can use https://codesandbox.io for that).

Comment: I agree with the above, you can also use the code editor provided as an option on your question.

Comment: I edited @Dekel. Added images to explain what im trying to achieve and added code that shows the problem

Comment: @NathanielFlick

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting the `Popover` component doesn't have a property to handle this situation. I ran into a similar issue on a smaller device when I had a long list of data in the popover. To fix this, I just set `top` myself on the `PaperProps` property of the `Popover` component. See below:

```
<Popover PaperProps={{ style: { top: myAnchor.current ? myAnchor.current.getBoundingClientRect().bottom : 0 } }}></Popover>
```

Comment: @Mumfordwiz no problem, let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score -1):

Don't do `overflow: scroll` on `root`. Instead, do `overflowY: auto` on `paper`.

[See codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pop-over-issue-mui-q4k1s?file=/src/SimplePopover.js) and play around.

**Try this:**

```js
overrides: {
      MuiPopover: {
        root: {
          // overflow: "scroll"
        },
        paper: {
          left: 50,
          top: "500px !important",
          height: 50,
          overflowY: "auto"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is not what I tried to do. look at the images i send, and the code